# Is it possible to change all anchor tags properties on a website at once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have recently learned that `target="_blank"` is vulnerable and we have to use `rel="noopener"`. I am working on a website project where all anchor tags are using the target attribute.

It is possible to change the colors of these `anchor texts` at once just by using:

```
a {color: blue;}
```

in the head of the website.

But If I try to do

```
a {
rel="noopener"
target ="_blank"
}
```

The above code does not have any effect. Because rel and `target` are not covered in `CSS`.

So how could someone set these `attributes` for the entire site?

Also, I tried searching on w3schools but they don't have any answer to it in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need JS.

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(a => {
   a.setAttribute("rel", "noopener");
   a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
});
```

Comment: This looks correct but is not working for me. I don't know why, I have added it as a JS in the head of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Find elements using Vanilla JS. Loop then change attributes.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]').forEach(function(el){
    el.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener');
});
```

Then apply CSS

```
a[target ="_blank"][rel="noopener"] {
    color: blue;
}
```